# How to convert MAC Address formats in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl, mac-address

I have to make a Perl script that gets a MAC address in the format HHHH.HHHH.HHHH where "H" is a hex digit, and give me a output of HH:HH:HH:HH:HH:HH. How can I make this conversion in Perl?

Here's an input text example:

```
System Information
Local port          :xgei-1/6/1
Group MAC address   :Nearest Bridge
Neighbor index      :1
Chassis type        :MAC address
Chassis ID          :4cf5.5b8b.f860
Port ID type        :Interface name
Port ID             :XGigabitEthernet0/0/1
Time to live        :109
Port description    :ZTE-2-C650-172.24.102.77
System name         :main-link-lab-cdi-sw-01
```

And here's my script's snippet where I treat the MAC Address data:

```
if ($linha =~m/^Chassis ID/){
            my($chassisID) = $linha=~ /:(.*)/g;
            $lldpInfo{$localInt}{"chassisID"} = $chassisID;
            print $chassisID."\n";  
}
```

In this case, I have to process the variable `$chassisID`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick and dirty approach could be to split the string on `.`, map the entries (assumed to be 4 characters each) into 2 character snippets separated by `:`, and then rejoin the results with `:` separators

```perl
my $chassisID = '4cf5.5b8b.f860';
# Transform the format:
$chassisID = join(':', map { substr($_, 0, 2).':'.substr($_, 2, 2) } split('\.', $chassisID));
print "ChassisID in MAC address format: $chassisID\n";
```

Output:

```
ChassisID in MAC address format: 4c:f5:5b:8b:f8:60
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [NetAddr::MAC](https://metacpan.org/pod/NetAddr::MAC) module from CPAN to parse and format MAC addresses in many different ways:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature qw/say/;
use NetAddr::MAC;

my $macaddr = '4cf5.5b8b.f860';
my $mac = NetAddr::MAC->new($macaddr);
say $mac->as_ieee; # 4c:f5:5b:8b:f8:60
```

Comment: Its a good approach aswell, but I should avoid modules because the customer's environment has limited access to the public internet.

Comment: "_should avoid modules..._" -- Understood, but that may result in added burden and code awkwardness as requirements evolve. Or may get near impossible -- what if you need sophisticated date-time processing, for example?  Did you consider "packing' your application with everything it needs, modules and all?  There are rather rounded tools for that in Perl.  Just a thought

Comment: Yeah, it can be really hard to write quality code with using only core modules, depending on what you're doing. I can't stand arbitrary restrictions like that.

Answer (score 1):

```perl
my $out = join ":", unpack "(H2)*", pack "n*", map hex, split /\./, $in;
```

---

If leading zeroes can't be omitted, you can use the following shorter solutions:

```perl
my $out = $in =~ s/\.//rg =~ s/..\K/:/rg;
```

```perl
s/\.//g, s/..\K/:/g for $s;                  # In-place
```